# VSCode. Html Project. Run and Debug. Launch Chrome against localhost doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code

Just installed Visual Studio Code (Version: 1.72.2 (user setup)).

Want to test debugging JavaScript in VSCode.

So, I created a Simple html and js file.

In VSCode Open folder and selected my Folder.

In VSCode selected Run and Debug.

Then selected Create a launch.json.

Selected Web App (Chrome).
launch.json created.

I pressed Start Debugging (F5) button

Chrome started but It shows a error:

---

> This site can’t be reached
> localhost refused to connect. Try:
>
> Checking the connection  Checking the proxy and the firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

---

Where to look and how to fix the web server configuration error for debugging?

[image]

--

I also checked the next launch.json configuration :

```
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome",
        "port": 9222,
        "request": "attach",
        "type": "chrome",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

The result of launching is modal window with message

> [Window Title]
> Visual Studio Code
> [Content] Cannot connect to the target at localhost:9222: Could not
> connect to debug target at http://localhost:9222: Could not find any
> debuggable target
>
> [Open 'launch.json'] [Cancel]

--
I also tested configuration "Launch Edge"

```
        "name": "Launch Edge",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "msedge",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

and got the similar error

'localhost refused to connect.'

Comment: You're launching Chrome. But where are you starting the server that actually runs on port 8080 (or 9222)?

Comment: According to this instruction, it is not necessary to start the web server separately.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging

Or is it necessary?